# Is there any way to Customize Active Directories exception/error message?

Tags: active-directory

I am using Active Directory as a data store for the users of my website. I have Active Directory throwing the following exception in case password does not meet any password policy constraint.

> The password supplied is invalid. Passwords must conform to the password strength requirements configured for the default provider.

Can I customize this error messages/notifications in any way to be them more specific?

What I want is that - If 'password history' is the constraint that is violated then the error message should say so (ex. `New password should be different than the last 10 used passwords`)

Comment: DOes this happen when users change their passwords? How are the users changing their passwords?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this to catch the error in code:[Security Policy and Password Complexity with Active Directory Membership Provider](http://www.rshelby.com/post/security-policies-and-password-complexity.aspx)

Comment: Wow, is this really the best way to do it?  So Microsoft's code is doing all this checking, yet returning no useful error message when it would be trivial to do so.  We have to basically re-implement the whole thing, returning a useful error message.  Nice going, Microsoft.